# Can Tarragon, Cinnamon basil, Rosemary, Spring onion, Chives and Parsley, be grown together?

Tags: herbs

I have a small planter that I wish to fill with different herb plants for cooking purposes. The plants I am looking to purchase are Tarragon, Cinnamon basil, Rosemary, Spring onion, Chives and Parsley. But before I make the purchase, I want to check that this combination will survive being grown together in the same planter?

Comment: I'd *bet* on the rosemary and tarragon fighting it out after winning over the others, but I **can't say for sure,** not having tried it. And the result might vary somewhat with the conditions your planter has - particularly in terms of light and drainage.

Comment: When you say a 'small planter', how small is it - a photo might help, along with knowing what part of the world you are in.